# How to adjust and make the width of a UILabel to fit the text size?

Tags: iphone

In my project, there is a `UILabel` with text. The font size is 16pt. The text contents are changed depending on different cases. I hope it can automatically adjust the width of `UILabel` to fit the total width of texts without stretching.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This assumes you have already set the font:

```
label.text = @"some text";
[label sizeToFit];
```

You will also need to define a maximum width, and tell your program what to do if sizeToFit gives you a width greater than that maximum.

Comment: sizeToFit method is a method of UIView.

Comment: how to define a maximum width?

Comment: The number of lines must be 1 for the width to adjust. If 0 it adjusts height. Also note this only seems to grow the UILabel, so make sure it's less wide in IB than all the text you'll be using.

Comment: It shrinks as well in iOS 7.

Comment: To define a maximum width you'd simply check `label.frame.size.width` after calling `sizeToFit`. If `label.frame.size.width` is > than your maximum width, you'd then adjust the size accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget that you have to check your auto layout constraints, if it has a fixed size it might not change on runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to set these properties within the storyboard?

Answer (score 21):

Here's how to do it, suppose the following `messageLabel` is the label you want to have the desired effect. Now, try these simple line of codes:

```
    // Set width constraint for label; it's actually the width of your UILabel
    CGFloat constrainedWidth = 240.0f;
    // Calculate space for the specified string
    CGSize sizeOfText = [yourText sizeWithFont:yourFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,constrainedWidth,sizeOfText.height)];
    messageLabel.text = yourText;
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;// This will make the label multiline
```

Comment: This is actually a really good answer... Just not for this specific question! This answer works well when you want to automatically adjust the *height* of a `UILabel` whilst maintaining a fixed width. That's in fact what I was looking for when I came across this page. I'd love to vote your answer up... but it doesn't answer the question asked. Good solution nevertheless and will probably help others who stumble across this page.

Comment: Thanks jon! Actually I was searching for this solution as well and incidentally I managed to make it,and then thought I should share it here. :) BTW,exactly what happened that time is that I didn't notice the question very well, so made the mistake,I think. Sorry for that,and happy that it helped you :D

Comment: could you post something similar for iOS 8?

Answer (score 14):

```
NSString *txt1=@"I am here.";
CGSize stringsize1 = [txt1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]]; 
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize1.width,hieght)];
[label setText:txt1];
```

Answer (score 7):

I see three options here.

First, make label's size big enough to hold any text. That's most simple, but does not always work well - depends on its surrounding views.

Second, Label can adapt size of the font for longer text (`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property). This is often not desirable, different fonts in elements might look ugly.

Last option is to programmatically resize the label according to its currently holding text. To calculate the size required to hold the text with current font use something like this:

```
CGSize textSize = [[someLabel text] sizeWithFont:[someLabel font] forWidth:someLabel.bounds.size.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: If we use UILineBreakModeWordWrap we can enter multiple lines on UILabel, How can I set the line space between two lines.

Answer (score 3):

If you set your font and its size already and if you have your frame defined, try using the following for these two common conditions:

```
if (label.text.length > maxCharPerLine) [label setNumberOfLines:0]; // infinite lines
else [label setNumberOfLines:1]; // one line only

// Adjust your font size to fit your desired width.
[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

Comment: Assuming you are attempting multiple line labeling then yes this is the correct approach. For single line labeling of course set number of lines to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using Auto Layout:

[image]

In the ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sampleLabel.text = "Electrical Maintenance and Repair"
    sampleLabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this.

```
CGSize stringsize = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]]; 
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,stringsize.width,height)];
[label setText: yourString];
```

Comment: this method is deprecated

Comment: and, when calling the new size measurement, you should use label.font, not the system font

Answer (score 1):

As sizeWithFont is depreciated in IOS 7.0 then you below code

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)



 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
        // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
        CGSize fontSize = [itemCat_text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
    } else {
        // code here for iOS 7.0
         fontSize = [itemCat_text sizeWithAttributes:
                           @{NSFontAttributeName:
                                 [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]}];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will be enough.

```
yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```